# Как хранить в vector переменные разного типа?

Tags: c++

Мне надо создать массив хранящий разные типы данных (string int и double) как правильно это все инициализировать? Хочу запихнуть все в один vector

Comment: В 90% случаев это говорит о том, что у вас дизайн не слишком... Например, вам придется держать информацию о том, что именно в данном конкретном элементе массива хранится, каждое обращение обвешивать лишней логикой проверок... Но, наверное, каждый должен набивать свои шишки сам, так что смотрите в сторону https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: Не соглашусь, 90% маловато))

Comment: Хм, перечитал вопрос. Может речь идёт о хранении структур вида `struct my_data {std::string a; int b; double c;}`?

Comment: Никак. У этих типов нет общего предка, поэтому никакой `std::vector<T>` не сможет хранить объекы таких типов унутре себя.

Comment: @PakUula контрпример - std::any https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type

Comment: @gbg правда? Какой компилятор это поддерживает, не подскажете? g++ 10.1 не умеет `vector<any>`. Ругается, пишет `vector<any> error: template argument 1 is invalid`, мол `note: ‘std::any’ is only available from C++17 onwards`,

Comment: --std=c++17 добавьте к опциям

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyStruct {
        int a;
        double b;
        std::string c;
    };
    std::vector <MyStruct> v;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]